# Highcharts. Marks on grid lines

Tags: highcharts, line, axis, marker

I'm trying to show my mark points on a Highcharts' linechart on the grid lines.

This is what I have got
[image]

Ass you can see on the picture, the markers are in the middle of the vertical grid lines **and not hover the grid lines**

Is there any way to change this?

Comment: Try posting your chart options, or better still, re-create it in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 8):

Please take look at example: http://jsfiddle.net/5h9dP/1/

```
xAxis: {
        tickInterval:1,
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        gridLineWidth: 1
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using categories, check that your tickmarkPlacement is set to 'on' instead of 'between'

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickmarkPlacement

If you are not using categories...make sure your data points and gridlines fall on the same data values...